# How to test whether two periodic sequences are the same with the least number of comparisons

Tags: algorithm

Program has for input 1 or more periods of both sequences. How to test whether these sequences are the same with the least number of comparisons.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Please, provide a concrete example.

Comment: Well idk this description of the problem is everything I got.

Comment: "Program has for input 1 or more periods of both sequences." Can't parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the smallest period of the two input strings, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620942/find-the-smallest-period-of-input-string-in-on) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347812/given-string-s-find-the-shortest-string-t-such-that-tm-s) which describe a solution using the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm.  Once you've found the strings' smallest periods then it's trivial to compare them.